PowerBI query: custom text column based on two other text columns' values
There is a table with each line being a unique project and its current status and delay.
I am trying to make a new column in PowerBI query that shows project status based on

"Status" with 2 unique values - Finished or null and
"Delay" with 3 unique values - "on time", "late" or "canceled".

I would like the new column's value to be
if Delay is "canceled" then "canceled"
if Delay is not "canceled" AND  Status is finished then "finished"
if  Delay is not "canceled" AND Status is not finished then "planned"
Could you please recommend me how to rewrite this multiple conditions function?
I have tried this function
= Table.AddColumn(Custom1, "New column",  each
if Text.Contains([Delay], "Canceled") then "Canceled" else
if [Delay]<>"Canceled" and Text.Contains([Status], "Finished") then "Finished" else
if [Delay]<>"Canceled" and [Status]<>"Finished"
then "Planned" else "other")
I get errors instead of planned in the new column

Nothing looks immediately wrong, but possibly wrong casing? You can rewrite your code like this and the casing shouldn't matter.
= Table.AddColumn(
    Custom1,
    "New column",
    each if Text.ToLower([Delay]) = "canceled" then "Canceled"
         else if Text.ToLower([Status]) = "finished" then "Finished"
         else "Planned"
)

